# How to run Matlab from the command line?

Tags: macos, matlab

Is it possible to run Matlab commands from Mac command line?

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but have you tried `matlab -nodesktop`?

Comment: I tried it but the command line doesn't recognize the command "matlab"

Comment: My guess is, you need to specify the full path.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `matlab` script is in the `bin` subdirectory of the MATLAB app bundle. On my machine, this means I can run it like so:

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a_Student.app/bin/matlab
```

If you want this bin directory on your path (so that you can just run `matlab`, `mex`, etc), edit or create a new text file called `.bash_profile` in the top level of your home directory with the following line:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a_Student.app/bin:$PATH
```

Replacing the "MATLAB_R2012a_Student" part with the name of your actual MATLAB app bundle. This will not come into effect for currently open terminals, but newly opened terminals should work properly.

Comment: I used the same way and it works. But if I want to keep the previous version of MATLAB and I want to run both on my machine? Could I add both paths?

Comment: Adding both paths won't help because the commands for each version of MATLAB have the same names - the computer isn't a mind reader, so it will just pick the first one in the list. Instead, you can create shell aliases like `alias matlab2012="/Applications/MATLAB_R2012.app/bin/matlab`. Then, running `matlab2012` would run that specific version. Shell aliases aren't magically saved, so add them to your `~/.bashrc` file to make sure the alias is set whenever you start your shell.

Comment: thank you so much, I didn't know that I could use that

Comment: You may want to specify some options so the GUI doesn't load, e.g. `.../bin/matlab -nodesktop -nosplash'`

Answer (score 1):

You need the full path to the MATLAB executable, and you can use the `-r` option to run a command in the MATLAB that you start, as per the doc [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/matlabunix.html).

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned above you need to first edit your .bash_profile file by adding the following line (replace 'MATLAB_R2020b' with your MATLAB version)

```
export PATH=/Applications/MATLAB_R2020b.app/bin:$PATH
```

Then after restarting the terminal you can open MATLAB by inserting the command

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2020b.app/bin/matlab
```

You can also run your .m scripts by defining the working directory folder and the executable scripts and their paths. You just need to add more commands to the above.

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2020b.app/bin/matlab -r "addpath(genpath('{Your working directory folder path}')); cd {Your working directory folder path}; {Your script name}; {Your other script name}; quit;"
```

Please find a more detailed description of MATLAB command line arguments from:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabmacos.html#d122e801165