# How to install Matlab R2014a on Mac 10.9.4 (in fact, a Mac Virtual Machine)?

Tags: java, macos, matlab

I try to install Matlab R2014a on Mac 10.9.4, which is a Virtual Machine in my Windows 7.

After open InstallForMacOSX.app, the logo things appear for a while, and then it says:
**Install Matlab quit unexpectedly.**

## Problem details are:

```
Process:         java [427]
Path:            /tmp/*/java
Identifier:      net.java.openjdk.cmd
Version:         1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  sh [389]
Responsible:     sh [358]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-09-08 01:02:34.324 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  7FAD146F-0E07-23E8-AB07-4C6408874BB4


Crashed Thread:  19  Java: Java2D Queue Flusher

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000103460000-0000000103471000 [   68K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /tmp/*

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
...
```

## In the log file, the report is :

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff8bdeefc8, pid=427, tid=40455

 JRE version: 7.0_11-b21
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.6-b04 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [libGL.dylib+0x1fc8]  glGetString+0xf

 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

## ************************

Both of them are of a huge length. I'm sorry I'm not familiar with Java things. I wonder what is going on here? I already install Java SE and JavaforOSX.

Comment: Are you sure that MATLAB does support installs on virtual machines?

Comment: Well, about two years ago, I indeed install it successfully on Mac 10.8, which is also in a virtual machines. But at that time it was Matlab R2012a or R2012b, I don't remember..

Comment: This is probably best handled through Mathworks support.

Comment: @nkjt, Okay, sounds reasonable, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar problem installing R2014a on a Mac OS virtual machine.  However, I got it working by doing something like this...

1) Download the latest java development kit from the oracle website [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)  (It might work with the java runtime environment on it's own also, if you don't want the entire JDK)

2) Run the matlab installer from a terminal, specifying the location of the new JRE.  See also [JRE error when trying to install Matlab Compiler Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515707/jre-error-when-trying-to-install-matlab-compiler-runtime) for more details, but the command for me (from within the MATLAB install directory) was

```
./install -javadir /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

At this point the installer worked basically as per normal, although there were errors with the Symbolic Math Toolbox, so I deleted the (faulty) installation, and ran the installer again as above, but without installing this toolbox.

3) Matlab didn't seem to open from the normal Applications shortcut, so I had to run it from a terminal and specify an alternative java virtual machine.  See [How to run Matlab from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248049/how-to-run-matlab-from-the-command-line) and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103056-how-do-i-change-the-java-virtual-machine-jvm-that-matlab-is-using-for-mac-os) for more details.  Note, you can export the MATLAB_JAVA environmental variable in your .bash_profile file, and you will need to restart/open a new terminal before the changes to your bash shell have an effect.

Good luck!

Comment: Good news. Now R2014b can be smoothly installed in Mac OS virtual machine. I've done that. You might want to upgrade it, too.